# getting dtype error while opening the .csv file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am getting below error, while opening the .csv file in jupyter notebook in windows environment.

```
Salaries = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')
```

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3057: DtypeWarning: Columns (3,4,5,6,12) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
>     interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

if I call the file I am able see the content of the file, however when I am applying `.mean()`, getting below error.

```
Salaries['BasePay'].mean()
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

tried applying another function

```
Salaries['BasePay'].max()
```

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Without the csv, it will be hard to say anything. It seams that some columns have strings and float in it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have downloaded the file from Kaggle.com. I trust the website. As I don't have an option to upload the file I am mentioning the file path. https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
read_csv(..., dtype={‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64'})
```

You need to specify the type of data in each column

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign `low_memory=False` to your path, as below:

```
Salaries = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv', low_memory=False)
```